# Why is power automate custom connector returning same results for different request URLs?

Tags: api, powerapps, power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector

I am trying to develop a custom connector on Microsoft Power Automate which connects to my Django API through an on-premises data gateway. Irrespective of the path names that I provide, it always returns the response body from the base API URL.

 For eg, the response body that I get for my base URL (*http://domain-name/*) is:

**Body**

```
{
  "ipaddresses": "http://domain-name/ipaddresses/",
  "vlans": "http://domain-name/vlans/"
}
```

Here, you can see that my response body contains the valid paths that is available for my API. But when I change my request URL to any of the above path URLs, I still get the same response body instead of the correct responses(-an array of IP addresses and VLANs, respectively). The response code that I am getting is 200, so I can't troubleshoot any errors there. Also, all the path URLs are working fine when accessed via browser or Postman. 
I am also including the request headers in my custom connector for your reference, below:
**Headers**

```
{
  "allow": "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS",
  "cache-control": "no-cache,no-store",
  "content-encoding": "gzip",
  "content-type": "application/json",
  "date": "Wed, 06 Jan 2021 09:45:02 GMT",
  "expires": "-1",
  "pragma": "no-cache",
  "referrer-policy": "same-origin",
  "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
  "vary": "Accept,Cookie,Accept-Encoding",
  "x-content-type-options": "nosniff,nosniff",
  "x-frame-options": "DENY,DENY",
  "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "true",
  "x-ms-request-id": "******",
  "x-powered-by": "ASP.NET"
}
```

Kindly help me where I am going wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For each request type, you need to create a unique `Action`, `Request` and `Response` in the Custom Connector.

**See here:**

- Multiple Actions
- Each with its own request path
- And response schema

[image]

Comment: I created the connector by loading from a Postman collection, so pretty much everything that you pointed was pre-filled. I also tried by changing the response schema from key-body-output by using 'Import from sample' and pasting the sample JSON output schema. But, nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Hm. Maybe you want something called "path templating" in your Custom Connector then? I [wrote about this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Custom-Connectors-how-to-pass-parameters/m-p/356530/highlight/true#M102146) a while ago. May work for your case.